# Firebase Hosting Setup - "Set up the workflow to run a build script before every deploy? (y/n)

Tags: progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

What exactly does this mean for Firebase Hosting Setup in CLI to "run a build script before every deploy?"

**Context:**
I'm using Firebase to host an Ionic PWA app, and I'm curious of the pros and cons of using Firebase vs other providers.
Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It simply means that before deploying, should a specific script be run? For example, you may need to run a command to build some sources. In React.js, you would need to build before deploying, so the command to enter would be:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: so what should I do? y or n ??

Comment: It depends. What language are you using? If react, then yes and type 'npm run build'

Comment: it might also require `npm ci` so you choose the option `y` and write `npm ci && npm run build` and it should work.

Comment: @Kurt I intend to deploy a Flutter web app. Should I answer yes or no?

Comment: How about no frameworks? Just Node js for the server side? Y or N?